# PHP PDO AJAX Query not working, my eyes are crossing

Tags: php, pdo

I am re-writing a file that will dynamically build queries to search and match any word in an string passed by an ajax event...

I cannot get the thing to return data.  It acts like everything worked perfectly, but it didn't.  All I get in firebug is success: true..which is good because that means there wasn't an error but my SQL results aren't being passed.

I know this code is going to be all over the place for you guys, but it doesn't work...

I've spent most of the day re-working this code so its not pretty or perfect yet, I just want it to return search results again...

Bill, if you are reading this, I didn't get a chance to look into the %LIKE alternatives you suggested last week ha...still waiting on your book in the mail.

Sorry to dump a ton of code on you guys but I just can't see what's wrong here.

```
function CreateOptions($columns, $num_elements, $condition="AND") {
$colcount = count($columns);
$optionString = " ";

for ($ii=0; $ii < $num_elements; $ii++) {
    if ($ii > 0)
        $optionString .= " AND (";

    for ($i=0; $i<$colcount; $i++) {
        if ($i>0)
            $optionString .= " OR ";

        $optionString .= $columns[$i] . " LIKE '%:search$ii%'";
    }

    //$optionString .= ")";
}

return $optionString;
}

include_once('../sys/core/init.inc.php');

$json = array();
$result = array();


if (isset($_POST['searchTerm'])){
try {
        $search = trim($_POST['searchTerm']);
    $search = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $search);
    $search = explode(" ", $search);
    $num_search_elements = count($search);

    switch($_POST['category']) {
        case ("account"):
        $querySyntax = "SELECT
                            idAccount, 
                FirstName,
                LastName,
                Email,
                Phone,
                CCCity,
                db_name.states.Abbreviation 
                FROM
                    db_name.account Right Join
                                    db_name.states On  
                                    db_name.account.CCState =
                                    db_name.states.ID 
                    WHERE";

            $cols = Array ("FirstName", "LastName", "Phone", "Email", "idAccount"); 


            $querySyntax .= CreateOptions($cols, $num_search_elements);

            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    $querySyntax .= " LIMIT 50";


                    // Build and run query (change to execute)
                    $dbs = $dbo->prepare($querySyntax);

                    for($i=0; $i<$num_search_elements; $i++) {
                        if ($dbs->bindValue(":search$i", $search[$i], (is_int($search[$i]) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR))) {
            // yea i know... nothing here its all below still
        } else {
            die("BIND_ERROR");
        }
    }

    $dbs->execute();

    // Put the array together
    $search_results = $dbs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //print_r($search_results);
    foreach($search_results as $col=>$val) {
        $result[$i][$col] = $val;
        $i++;
        //echo "$col >> $val";
    }           

    $stmt = null;
    $result["success"] = true;




}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $result["success"] = false;
    $result["error"] = $e->getMessage() . " >> SQL: $querySyntax";

}



} else {
$result["success"] = false;
$result["error"] = "INVALID DATA";
}

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($result);
```

Here is the generated SQL taken straight from Firebug when I tell it to echo the query:

```
SELECT
idAccount,
FirstName,
LastName,
Email,
Phone,
CCCity,
db_name.states.Abbreviation
FROM
db_name.account Right Join
db_name.states On db_name.account.CCState =
    db_name.states.ID 
WHERE 
FirstName LIKE '%:search0%' OR 
LastName LIKE '%:search0%' OR
phone LIKE '%:search0%' OR 
email LIKE '%:search0%' OR 
idAccount LIKE '%:search0%' 
LIMIT 50
```

replace :search0 with "mar" you get this from my db in terminal and phpmyadmin:

```
1   Mar     <my real name> myemail@email    1231231234  City    FL
2   Martin  Short   mshort@movies.com   2147483647  Beverly Hills   CA
4   Martin  Short   mshort@email.com    2146791243  Beverly Hills   CA
5   Martin  Short   mshort@movies.coms  2146791243  Beverly Hills   CA
```

Comment: I spit out the query, and replaced :search0 with a search term that I know will work, punched it into the mysql terminal and it worked fine, so its something with my PHP/PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reson it was not working was because I had the bound search iterations (:search0...) in '' which turns it into a literal which will not match anything in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
```

Check your http results using something like Firebug/Network view - it might be returning correctly, just isn't getting parsed in Javascript.

Comment: Why would he want to be doing that ? He's using AJAX and needs to send json content-type. Plus he said he's query isn't returning results.

Comment: I'm using Firebug, in Net I get this under the JSON and Response tab {"success":true}

Comment: @tftd I had the exact same problem as he describes, trying a `.getJSON` call. I changed my `Content-Type` to `text/javascript` from `application/json` and presto - it worked.

Comment: @guyfromfl you should also be able to see the full response (the data sent) by drilling into the call it made. Did you try changing the content-type as I suggested?

Comment: @Matt, the data being sent is correct and working.  This ajax handler was written even more poorly than this one before and decided to re-do it.  I tried text/javascript but get the same response... the success variable I crated is returning true.

Comment: Are you calling it from the same website as this script? What does your call look like? And did you check your return headers and data?

Comment: My post data is {category: "account",  searchTerm: "ma"} (what I typed in the search box.

Comment: The calling script was working fine, since it is sending the same exact data as it was before, I'm leaning toward it being in my "new" code I posted.  I know with scripting its not always the case, but all the data going to the server looks good.  I'm deving locally right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the SQL query you generate.
I would suggest you get your query out of PDO and try it in phpmyadmin or mysql console.
If it works there, then your php script is not generating the sql properly. If it's that case it'll be a lot of help if you show us the real sql query and the results from your database.

Edit:
Try replacing this:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_search_elements; $i++ ) {
    if ( $dbs->bindValue(":search$i", $search[ $i ], (is_int($search[ $i ]) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR)) ) {
```

With this

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_search_elements; $i++ ) {
    $var = ":search".$i;
    if ( $dbs->bindValue($var, $search[ $i ], (is_int($search[ $i ]) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR)) ) {
```

And see if it works.

Comment: I did echo the SQL back to the script just to catch it in firebug, I updated my OP with the query.  When I replace :search0 with mar (the search string I know will return 4 results, it works perfectly.

Comment: Good idea, I changed it but still returning the same success: true :/

Comment: Hmm.. From what I see you shouldn't be having :search0 on all of the columns. Shouldn't that be incremented +1 on every new column ?

Comment: Nope, whats happening is if you search for "Martin Short" it will see there are 2 words there, then turn the SQL into WHERE FirstName="Martin" OR FirstName="Short" across all of the fields.. Martin would be search0 and short would be search1 so I can bind those values later

Comment: hmm explaining that just pointed out a logic error when it will work on multiple words, but searching for "mar" should still work

Comment: Do you have error_reporting switched on? There may be some notifications going on there that can help?

Comment: i do not. i will try that tomorrow. its time to go home. thanks for the help!

Comment: I re-wrote a very simplified version of this query in a test.php and it's returning an empty set as well

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be in this line:

```
foreach($search_results as $col=>$val) {
    $result[$i][$col] = $val;
    $i++;
    //echo "$col >> $val";
}
```

At this point in the code $i starts as the value of $num_search_elements, and counts upward from there. It is never re-initialized and set to 0 after a previous loop in the code which uses $i to count up to $num_search_elements.

What happens when you print_r($result) after the above loop? What happens when you print_r($search_results) before this loop? Do they match?

The above code could be replaced with:

```
foreach($search_results as $col=>$val) {
    $result[][$col] = $val;
}
```

Which will index upward starting from 0.

Comment: You are very right about not initing i...I need to start using better var names just in case..lol... but print_r gave me this for both variables: Array
(
)
{"success":true}

Comment: Also you should be careful with the $i variable. You're using it on two places - `for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_search_elements; $i++ )` and the pasted code from @dqhendricks

Comment: @guyfromfl I imagine this means that your query is returning an empty result set. What do you see when you print the generated sql string?

Comment: @tftd that is exactly what I was explaining in my post.

Comment: In the PHP script it is empty, when I query myself it works. I added the generated SQL query to my OP and the results returned from phpmyadmin when I repalce the :search0 with "mar"

Comment: maybe a problem where its binding the data?

Comment: From the look of the query you generated, I would say at least one of you problems is within CreateOptions(). Each named variable within your query is named Search0, when they should be named Search0, Search1, Search2, etc. I imagine there are also other issues with this code.

Comment: @dqhendricks, it's the same search string tho.  the string "mar" is being queried across all the columns.  so then I would have 5 searchx="mar" that I would bind.  I thought that you could reuse a bound place holder, no?

Comment: no. it only allows one placeholder per bound variable in my experience.

Comment: @dqhendricks  I wrote a simple file and reused placeholders, it works fine.

Comment: @guyfromfl interesting. the PDO::prepare documentation states that "you cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement"

Comment: @dqhendricks strange, it works as long as :search is the same, I wonder if they are stating the obvious about it acts as a variable? Idk.. Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: @dqhendricks if you read the last comment of the PDO::prepare documentation, it explains why it's working, although it's not really working...so I guess you are right